# Unwanted message when opening the shell

Tags: linux, shell, uninstallation

I just uninstalled a program (ros) from my computer (ubuntu) using the ubuntu software center.
However, since this moment, whenever I open a shell, I get the following message:

```
bash: /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I can't find it (even though I looked into the hidden files in my home folder)

Comment: Then check `/etc/profile`

Comment: there is nothing related in /etc/profile. however, the last lines of .bashrc are: 
# Added
#  make sure virtualenvwrapper is loaded and is using Python 3
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON='/usr/bin/python3'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

Comment: Shall I just remove these lines? I actually think I didn't uninstall ros correcly (there is still a ros folder in etc for instance). Shall I just delete this folder? Thanks!

Comment: Before removing those lines comment them

Comment: It is not too late for a correct uninstall

Comment: I tried [uninstalling] (http://answers.ros.org/question/57213/how-i-completely-remove-all-ros-from-my-system/) ros using `apt-get remove ros-*` however, when I opened the shell, the same message appeared. I then commented the lines and, as expected, the message doesn't appear anymore. Yet, uninstallation should have removed this message no?

Comment: I think so. Try `apt-get purge ...`

Comment: it removed some other files but the extra line remains.